# Why is 'animation-timeline' needed

Tags: css, animation

I was looking at [this pen](https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/eYbYydG) and was wondering what "animation-timeline" actually does ?

If we take this bit of css:

```
    p {
  width: 50vw;
  resize: both;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  padding:10vmin;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
    animation: fill-up both linear;
    animation-timeline: --section;
    animation-range: cover;
    margin: 0;
}
@keyframes fill-up {
    to {
        --progress: 1;
    }
}
```

The keyframes are defining the animation, they are called using "animation: fill-up" so I do not get what the "animation-timeline: --section" does. I did read the doc but I must've missed something. Is it related to the parent-children inheritance ?

Any help or explanation greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's experimental and hardly supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timeline